# Configure .eds file to map channels of a CANopen Client PLC

Tags: automation, mapping, plc, canopen

In Order use a PLC as a Client (formerly  “Slave”), one has to configure the PDO channels, since the default values of the manufacturer are often not suitable. In my case, I need the PDOs so send INT valued instead of the default UNSIGNED8 (see. Picture).

[image]

Therefore my question: What kind of workflow would you recommend, to map the CANopen Client PDO channels?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workflow suitable, however I appreciate any improvements and recommendations from your side!

1. Start by locating the .eds file from the manufacturer. The image show this in the B&R Automation Studio Programming Environment

[image]

2. Open the file in a eds. Editor. I found the free Vector CANEds Editor very useful. Delete all RxPODs and RxPDO mappings that you don’t need.
   [image]
3. Assign the needed Data Type (e.g. INTEGER16) and Channel Name (“1 Byte In (1)”).
   [image]
4. Add the necessary PDOs and PDO mapping from the database. (This might actually be a bug, but if you just edit the PDOs without deleting and recreating them, I always receive error messages)

[image]

[image]

5. Map the Date to the Channels

[image]

6. Don't forget to write the number of channels in the first entry (in this image: 1601sub0)

[image]

7. Check the eds file for Errors (press F5) and copy&paste the eds file to the original location point 1.)
8. Add the PLC Client device in Automation Studio and you should see the correct mappings.

[image]

(PS: I couldn't make the images smaller ... any recommendations about formating this question are welcome!)